# Dynamically generating Ge'ez unicodes

Tags: unicode, utf-8

[image]

Hi. If you look at the image above, you will see a set of very weird-looking characters displayed along with some Latin characters. The weird ones are Eritrean characters. They are the characters we use in my country. So, to go strait to the point, I am hoping to create even the simplest possible bit of software or maybe even a batch file (if possible) to help me make these characters applicable on the web and make PCs understand and display them when being typed. Just like Arabic, Hindu, Chinese... characters are used. I think, since the question of 'creating a language' is often rare or because I may not know the correct term to use, when I searched the internet to find any tutorial or even a freelancer or anything, all I got was... nothing. So, I am hoping, if anyone can give me a step-by-step guide, or even just a clue about how to create this, would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like all of those characters are defined in Unicode.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigrinya_language
You should be able to include these in web content (with UTF-8 encoding) or you could use HTML entities like &#4696; for 'ቘ'.

Comment: Do these characters have anything in common with the Ethiopic characters (downloadable from [Unicode Code Charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/)), with codes in the ranges U+1200..U+137C, U+1380..U+1399, U+2D80..U+2DDE, and U+AB00..U+AB2E?  If not, then you're likely to need to use some of the private-use character ranges (U+E000..U+F8FF, or U+F0000..U+10FFFF), at least until you get the Eritrean characters recognized by Unicode.

Comment: @ddoxey - I have always thought some software program is needed to make the characters be displayable in any PC, otherwise you can not see the characters. But, it seems I was wrong, because if you can see the `&#4696` in your PC, then it means they are view-able in all browsers without installing software. I never knew what defined unicode meant until now. Does this mean I can create a script on my site that changes the little images to html codes and post the characters..? If so, It would be a life saver idea.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, they are same with Ethiopian characters.

Comment: In that case, if you can see the characters in the answer below, you should be OK (using the HTML encodings if that's the only way it will work; but try UTF-8).  Increasingly, Unicode coverage is getting better.  You may not have all the crazy font choices that apply to the Latin-1 code set, but you usually have workable representations.

Comment: @Eritrea Again, no extra work is required. Just write the characters directly like you're writing English characters right now.

Comment: I am writting this '&#4696' character in the hope of getting the letter which ddoxey has submit, but nothing is showing up

Comment: why isn't &#4696 converted then?

Comment: @Eritrea Because you're just typing the six characters &#4696 like you would type anything else. The operating system/input system doesn't convert characters just because you type a &# followed by a number. Anyway, that's a problem with input, not with displaying. Doesn't your keyboard have letters in your language? If it doesn't, right-click on the language icon at the right of the taskbar and select **Configuration**. In the **General** tab click the **Add** button and look for your language in the list of languages. (Continued below...)

Comment: Then click the checkbox for you language and click **Accept**, and also click **Accept** in the previous window. Then, when you're in the browser window, click the language icon in the taskbar and select your language. You should now be able to write characters with your keyboard.

Comment: @Eritrea the format of HTML entities (which is the technical term for these number combinations) is `&stuff;` where `stuff` can be a predefined or self defined name e.g `&raquo;` or as in your case, a numeric character representation. Its format is `&#number;` e.g. `&#4696;`. Note the respective leading and trailing characters.

Comment: @samayo Hello, I have been trying to decode the languages to learn the original language, are any of these letters considered "final letters"?

Comment: @Decrypted Hi. I don't understand what you meant by 'final letters'. I think Wikipedia can give you all the info you need about the history, other than that .. you have to clarify my question, because I don't get it.

Comment: @samayo To clarify, in Hebrew and Arabic languages that came down from Shem they would use final letters. The Mem for example. If found at the end of a word they would use a final Mem, basically a Mem that looked different but carried a different letter value. They did this also with the Kaph, Nun, Pey and the Tsade. Arabic then took these final letters and made full letters to them gave them more forms. Greek also has letter values that match up(some) to the character development through time. So the goals to find which brother started these "final forms" or if there since Noah.

Comment: I am not sure. I speak both Amharic and Tigrigna, and we have no 'Mem' or final letter. 'final letter' is a very ambiguous term, final letter of what? verbs, nouns, adjectives... anyone I learned those languages while growing up, so I won't be able to give you any more insight. I'm not good with the semantics. But, check out wikipedia .. I'm sure it can help or http://memhr.org/

Comment: @Decrypted: I realize this response is very late, but it may help someone searching for answers in the future... 
While most of the languages (incl. Amharic & Tigrinya) written with the Ethiopic script are Semitic languages like Hebrew & Arabic (Amharic having the 2nd most speakers after Arabic of all Semitic languages), and their writing systems share the same source "proto-script", Ethiopic evolved quite differently.
The characters have only one form; no uppercase or lowercase sets, no positional forms (initial, final, etc.), the characters have no cursive or connected forms/variants.

Comment: Because the vowels for each syllograph (equivalent to a "letter" in an alphabet) are indicated by adding/modifying the the original consonant character they follow using (mostly) predictable patterns (as you can see in the rows of the chart above),  all the syllographs after the first one in each are sometimes referred to as "forms" of that initial character.

Comment: Although the term "order" which is used with a number to specify which column (and hence which vowel it represents) is a more accurate description, and is also the widely accepted terminology in use.
All the character derived from a single letter in the old form of the writing system before vowels were encoded (which, in a number of cases includes 2 rows, and as many as six rows!) are all referred to as being past of the same "family" of that proto-letter.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your question asks "how to create a language", so I will describe all the pieces that need to be in place for a new language (or more accurately, writing system). You ask specifically about the Eritrean alphabet, so I will provide specific examples of how that is supported on modern systems, and try to provide you pointers for the pieces you are missing. The answer is long, and provides lots of links, to support the two explanations.

To work with a script like [Ge'ez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge%27ez_script) (also known as Ethiopic, the script used to write Amharic in Ethiopia and Tigrinya in Eritrea) you need a few things. The first is a way to encode the characters; a set of numbers representing each character, that the computer can use to represent the text. Luckily, [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) has become widespread, and Unicode is designed to be a universal character set that includes all of the world's languages. Unicode 3.0 introduced Ethiopic in the [range U+1200-U+137F](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1200.pdf), and later versions added supplements of more obscure characters in the ranges [U+1380-U+1394](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1380.pdf), [U+2D80-U+2DDF](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2D80.pdf) and [U+AB00-U+AB2F](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UAB00.pdf).  If you wanted to support a language that Unicode didn't yet support, you would either need to use the [private use area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_%28Unicode%29) and define your own mapping of characters to code points, or [submit a proposal](http://www.unicode.org/pending/proposals.html) to have your script added to Unicode; for example, see the proposal for [Ethiopic](ftp://ftp.ethiopic.org/pub/info/uni-proposal.txt).

Now, Unicode is just a [character set](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#character_set); an abstract mapping between characters and numbers. To actually transmit these characters as a sequence of bytes, you use a [character encoding](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#character_encoding_form). There are many encodings; some of them, like [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) only cover a subset of the full Unicode character set, while others, like [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), cover the full range. For documents on the web, UTF-8 is the recommended character encoding; you should never use anything else if you can help it. In UTF-8, you can write Ge'ez directly in the document, for example: ኤርትራ. One thing to watch out for is that some programs (especially on Windows) will offer you "Unicode" as an encoding, when they mean UTF-16; you want to make sure to choose UTF-8, as it's more efficient and more compatible with a wider variety of software.

If you are using encodings that don't cover the full range of Unicode, or you don't have a good way to type those characters, and you are writing HTML or XML, you can use [numeric character references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) instead. To do this, you write the Unicode code point of the character you want to refer between `&#` and `;`. You can write the number in decimal, or in hexadecimal prefixed with an `x`. For example, ሀ can be written `&#x1200;` or `&#4608;` (the semicolon at the end is important; it wasn't working for you in the comments because you were missing it).

Now that you have a character set, and a way of encoding it, you need a way to display it. Some scripts are easier to display in others. For all scripts, you need a [font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font); a file defining how each character looks. A font contains a collection of glyphs, or drawings of each character. Some scripts, like the [Latin alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet) (the alphabet used for English and most European languages) are relatively simple; each character is a separate glyph, and how they are drawn doesn't depend on what characters come before or after (though [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) and [ligatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) can make it a little more complicated). Others, like [Arabic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet) and [Indic scripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmic_scripts) are written in cursive, where letters join to each other so how they are drawn can depend on the characters near them. These languages require special rendering support like [Uniscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows, [Pango](http://www.pango.org/) on Linux, or advanced font technology like [Apple Advanced Typography](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TTRefMan/RM06/Chap6AATIntro.html) or [Graphite](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=projects&item_id=graphite_home).

Luckily, Ge'ez is a fairly simple writing system, that doesn't require any specialized rending support or advanced font systems. Each of the characters is a separate glyph, and it doesn't require any reordering. So a normal [OpenType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType) font, displayed with the rendering systems already available on most computers, will do the job. But you still need the font in order to be able to display the characters. To create you own font, you can use [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/) (a free/open source tool), [Fontographer](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontographer/), [FontLab Studio](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/), or other similar software.

For Ethiopic, you don't need to create your own. There are [numerous fonts available](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Ethiopic.html) that include the Ethiopic characters, but one that I would recommend is [Abyssinica SIL](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=AbyssinicaSIL) from [SIL](http://www.sil.org/) (the Summer Institute of Linguistics), which does a lot of great work for minority languages and writing systems. Their fonts are available under a [free license](http://scripts.sil.org/OFL), that allows you to use the font, redistribute the font, and modify the font, so their fonts are quite flexible and can be used in a wide variety of situations. Windows ships with [Nyala](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1623), which includes Ethiopic characters, since Windows Vista, and [Ebrima](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=2114), which added support for Ethiopic characters in Windows 8; so people on Windows Vista or later should be able to view Ethiopic characters already. Mac OS X ships with [Kefa as of 10.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5154).

Once you have the font, you will be able to view Ethiopic characters. But other people reading your documents might not have those fonts (if they are using an older version of Windows or Mac OS X, if they didn't install all of the fonts that came with Windows, or the like), in which case the characters will probably show up as boxes or question marks on their machine. You could give those people a redistributable font like Abyssinica SIL, or they could buy a font that includes Ethiopic characters, but that can be inconvenient. For working with word processor documents or plain text, that's probably the best you can do; they will need the font installed on their computer to be able to display the text. If you create a PDF on your computer, it should embed the fonts that it needs to display the text, so creating a PDF can be a convenient way to include uncommon fonts with your document.

On a web page, you can use [web fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-resources) to link to a font from your stylesheet, allowing the users web browser to load that font for that web page. Web fonts are supported [all the way back to IE 6](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface), and in recent versions of most other web browsers, so they are actually quite widely supported. Different web browsers support different font file formats ([EOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_OpenType), [TTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType), [OpenType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType), [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html), and [WOFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Open_Font_Format)), and slightly different syntaxes for the CSS (older versions of IE are based on an older draft), so it can be a bit tricky to make a page that is compatible with all browsers. Luckily, people have automated that process. Some web fonts are available online from [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) or [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface), but sadly, I couldn't find any Ethiopic fonts already hosted. However, you can [upload a font to FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator), and it will convert it into all of the major formats, and provide example CSS that will work on all modern browsers. Note that you should only do this with fonts that allow web embedding; not all fonts do. Since Abyssinica SIL is available under the Open Font License, you can use it, and I've run it through FontSquirrel for you; you can [see how it works](http://ephemera.continuation.org/stackoverflow/webfontkit-20121124-164442/abyssinicasil-r-demo.html) (check out the Glyphs & Languages tab), or [download the kit](http://ephemera.continuation.org/stackoverflow/webfontkit-20121124-164442.zip). To use it, just put the font files (`.ttf`, `.eot`, `.svg`, and `.woff`) on your server in the same directory as your CSS, and include the following in your CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'abyssinica_silregular';
    src: url('abyssinicasil-r.eot');
    src: url('abyssinicasil-r.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('abyssinicasil-r.woff') format('woff'),
         url('abyssinicasil-r.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('abyssinicasil-r.svg#abyssinica_silregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Now that you know how to encode Ethiopic, view Ethiopic characters, and share documents containing Ethiopic characters, you are probably going to want to type them into documents. If you are using HTML, you could just type the numeric character reference described above. In other documents, you could just copy and paste the characters from a chart of all of them, like the Wikipedia page. But that would become pretty cumbersome. Depending on your system and settings, you can also use [Unicode Hex Input](https://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes) to enter arbitrary Unicode characters, but that is also cumbersome.

To fully support typing a script on your computer, you need a [keyboard layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout) or [input method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method). Some scripts can be typed with a simple keyboard layout, which says which keys correspond to which characters. If a script has more characters than there are keys on the keyboard, Shift and Alt (or Option on the Mac) can be used to map to more characters. [Dead keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) can also be used to expand the range of characters that you type; dead keys are sequences of two or more keystrokes that produce a single glyph; for example, on Mac OS X, to type "á", you can type <kbd>Option-E</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>. To create a keyboard layout on Windows, you can use the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665). Mac OS X uses [an XML format](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2056/_index.html) for keyboard layouts, so you can create one directly, or use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) from SIL to create one more easily. On systems using X11 (like Linux), you can [create your own XKB layouts](http://hektor.umcs.lublin.pl/%7Emikosmul/computing/articles/custom-keyboard-layouts-xkb.html).

If you need more characters than can be supported with modifiers and dead keys, like typing Chinese or Japanese, then you need a full-fledged input method. An input method allows you to run arbitrary code to map what someone types into the text it produces; for example, in a Japanese input method, you may type a phonetic representation of what you you are writing, and it will show you a drop down list of possible characters that match that representation, allowing you to choose the appropriate ones. Windows provides the [Input Method Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for writing input methods, Mac OS X the [Input Method Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/InputMethodKitFrameworkRef/_index.html), and X11 has a few ways to do it, such as [SCIM](http://www.scim-im.org/) and [iBus](https://code.google.com/p/ibus/).

The [standard input method](http://keyboards.ethiopic.org/specification/) for Ethiopic makes extensive use of dead keys. It looks like the most popular existing input method for Ethiopic is [Keyman](http://www.tavultesoft.com/ethiopic/), which is a commercial input method that works on Mac and Windows, and in addition there's a free variant, [KMFL](http://kmfl.sourceforge.net/), that works on Linux. SIL has [keyboard downloads](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=AbyssinicaSIL_Download) for this input method; they also have a keyboard layout for Mac OS X which uses dead keys to achieve the same thing. Mac OS X has more extensive dead key support, so it doesn't require an input method to support this form of input, while on Windows you need to use an input method like Keyman to be able to enter input this way. Google has a free input method for Windows, [Google Input Tools for Windows](http://www.google.com/inputtools/windows/index.html), which supports Amharic, and allows you to [customize its input schemes](http://www.google.com/inputtools/windows/canonical.html); you could try adapting their Amharic support for Tigrinya.

If you just need to support input on a web site, you could do this in JavaScript, by writing an input method in JavaScript that transliterates from what someone types into Ethiopic. I do not know of any existing frameworks for doing this; however, I have found [Korean](http://www.sayjack.com/type/korean/) and [Japanese](http://jime.sourceforge.jp/javascriptime/) input methods implemented in JavaScript. You could take a look at how those are implemented. Upon looking further, I've found that Tavultesoft, who make Keyman, also have [KeymanWeb](http://www.tavultesoft.com/keymanweb/), a JavaScript based input method that you can buy and embed in your site. MediaWiki also has an input method extension [Narayam](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Narayam), that includes a JavaScript based input method for MediaWiki based sites like Wikipedia, which includes an experimental Amharic input method. There is also a [draft W3C IME API](http://www.w3.org/TR/ime-api/), which helps provide an interface between web apps and native IMEs, as well as JavaScript based IMEs. Given that it's still a draft, I don't know if it is yet supported anywhere.

With all the above (a character set, encoding, fonts, rendering support, and an input method), you will be able to create, share, and view documents in your script. If that's all you need, great; the above will allow you to work with documents in a given script. But for full support for a language on your computer, not just its script or writing system, there are two more pieces that you need: a [locale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale), and your software to be localized (translated and adapted) for your language.

A locale specifies how programs should manipulate text in a given script, language, culture, and/or encoding. There are many common text processing operations that programs do: displaying numbers, displaying dates and times, sorting strings or names, and so on. How these should work can differ based on the language, script, and culture of the person using the program; for instance, in Swedish "ü" is sorted along with "y", while in English and German it's sorted along with "u". Differences may not be based on language: both Mexico and Spain use Spanish, but in Mexico numbers are displayed with `.` as the decimal separator (1½ is written "1.5"), while in Spain `,` is used as the decimal separator (1½ is written "1,5"). A locale specifies all of these rules. Because the locale can vary based on language, culture, and sometimes other factors, the language and country are usually used to specify the locale, and other information can be used as well.

The most widely used standard for naming locales is [RFC 4646 (BCP 47)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4646). Locales are usually specified as "*ln*-*CC*" with the language code *ln* and country code *CC*: US English is en-US, British English is en-UK, and French in France is fr-FR. If more information needs to be specified, it can be included. For instance, [Serbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serbian_language) can be written with either Latin or [Cyrillic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script), and so Serbian in Serbia can be either sr-Latn-CS or sr-Cyrl-CS. Tigrinya in Eritrea is written ti-ER.

There are a variety of different formats for defining the rules that a particular locale has. Windows uses NLP files, a custom format that can be created with [Microsoft Locale Builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163506.aspx). POSIX (Unix/Linux) locales can be created using [localedef](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html). Many systems these days are moving towards the [Unicode Common Locale Data Registry](http://cldr.unicode.org/), which specifies a standardized format for locale data as well as a comprehensive database of locales for many of the worlds languages. [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) is a library for C and Java (and used by many other environments) for manipulating Unicode text according to Unicode rules and locale data; they have a good [browser](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp) for the data from the CLDR and their own locale data. For example, take a look at their entry for [ti-ER](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?d_=en&_=ti_ER).

Finally, for full support of a language, you need to translate the software itself into that language. There are, of course, many pieces of software, and each one contains many strings that need to be translated. Some software is not designed to be translated; it has not been [internationalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization). Some software can only be translated by whoever created it; the strings are built into the program and cannot be easily modified by a third party. But it is possible to localize some software, translating it to your language and culture. If the software has already been localized for several other languages and cultures, it is likely to be flexible enough to support a new language, and if it uses formats that are easily modifiable for localization information, it can be modified by third parties.

For instance, applications on Mac OS X store their localization data in separate files within the application bundle. There is a tool called AppleGlot (you need to register for the [Mac Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/) and go to the downloads area to find it) which can help you extract that data, provide a file with all of the strings which need to be translated, and allow you to combine that with the application again once you have. For open source software, such as much software available on Linux, you can work with the developers to provide translation. Some software uses [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html) for translation strings, which use the PO file format that you can edit using [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/). Some uses Qt, for which you can use [Qt Linguist](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/linguist-manual.html). Or for dealing with a wide variety of formats, you can use a commercial offering like [Swordfish](http://www.maxprograms.com/products/swordfish.html) or [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/).

Of course, no one person can do all of the above; it takes many people working together to build support for a new language on modern computer systems. This is all intended to be a high-level tour of all of the components that go into language support for a given language, with references that will help you follow up on whichever aspects you would like to work on, as well as demonstrate what already works for Tigrinya and the Ge'ez script.

Comment: I am just about to go to sleep, but this is the first thing I will read when I wake up tomorrow, I think this is 'the answer of answers' I am sure this is more than I was looking for, can't thank you enough. I will check it tommorow, as I am tired & can't understand anything now.

Comment: @Eritrea Glad to help, good luck reading it in the morning, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is just brilliant!!

Comment: @BrianCampbell I tried to create a new keyboard layout using windows keyboard layout creator. The biggest challenge was that I want to map a key to a character and the next key can modify the previously typed character. For example: typing b results in ብ and then if I press e next, it will change the ብ into a በ. Do you think I can implement this using MKLC. If Text Services Framework is the only option, then how do we achieve that? Thanks

Comment: @BrianCampbell, I have recently begun studying Amharic and have been using the unicode input method, which has hindered my studies.  Thank you for this thorough response.  I will be adding new tools to my arsenal.

Comment: This is one of the most thorough and complete answers I've ever seen on Stack Overflow, and I've been an active user for much of the last 11 years or so. Wow.

Answer (score 4):

If they are Unicode characters they should be displayable just like characters of any other language. I googled it and found this, hopefully they're the same ones you're asking about:

የ ዩ ዪ ያ ዬ ይ ዮ

ዸ ዺ ዻ ዼ ዽ  ዾ

See? No extra work required to display them on web browsers or other programs.

---

These are characters from the Unicode Ethiopic set (U+1200..U+137C), encoded in UTF-8:

Line 1:

- የ = 0xE1 0x8B 0xA8 = U+12E8 = ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE YA
- ዩ = 0xE1 0x8B 0xA9 = U+12E9 = ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE YU
- ዪ = 0xE1 0x8B 0xAA = U+12EA = ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE YI
- ያ = 0xE1 0x8B 0xAB = U+12EB = ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE YAA
- ዬ = 0xE1 0x8B 0xAC = U+12EC = ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE YEE
- ይ = 0xE1 0x8B 0xAD = U+12ED = ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE YE
- ዮ = 0xE1 0x8B 0xAE = U+12EE = ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE YO

Line 2:

- ዸ = 0xE1 0x8B 0xB8 = U+12F8 = ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE DDA
- ዺ = 0xE1 0x8B 0xBA = U+12FA = ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE DDI
- ዻ = 0xE1 0x8B 0xBB = U+12FB = ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE DDAA
- ዼ = 0xE1 0x8B 0xBC = U+12FC = ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE DDEE
- ዽ = 0xE1 0x8B 0xBD = U+12FD = ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE DDE
- ዾ = 0xE1 0x8B 0xBE = U+12FE = ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE DDO

Comment: Thank for the answer, but if they are displayable just like any other character, then why are we obliged to download and install other softwares/applications to see the texts appear as they are? because, i can tell you if I was to remove the fonts from my pc i would not be able to see them

Comment: I haven't installed any fonts on my PC and I can see them no problem. What operating system and web browser (+ versions) are you using?

Comment: I have windows 7+ google chrome. Normally, everyone installing the softwares provided by third party to view and specially read these characters. This software to be exact: http://www.tavultesoft.com/keyman/download.php
I don't know what really is going on, but I am trying to create a site like http://freetyping.geezedit.com/ even those this is created by flash, I want to create one with Javascript and Jquery. Do you know where to find/hire people who can do that?

Comment: Sorry, don't know much about web development, but if you know how to create the site independently from language, you can create it in English, Eritrean dialects, or any other language. That has been my point all along. (BTW I'm using Windows Vista and IE9, so I don't know why you can't see the characters without installing additional fonts.)

Answer (score 4):

Using Ethiopian characters on web pages is mostly a matter of fonts these days. (You may also have a problem with entering them conveniently, but this depends on your authoring environmentPeople using e.g. Windows 7 have at least one font containing them, but old computers typically lack such fonts. The following fonts contain them (there may be others):

[Code 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code2000), was freeware, the author has disappeared, so the status is obscure

[Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html), a free bitmap font

[FreeSerif](http://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/), a free font

[Nyala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyala_%28typeface%29), distributed with some versions of Windows

[SunExt-A](http://www.alanwood.net/downloads/index.html), a free font

[Fixedsys Excelsior](http://www.fixedsysexcelsior.com/), a free bitmap font I suppose (haven’t tested)

I would probably use FreeSerif as a downloadable font, with `@font-face`.

Answer (score 2):

Just came accross the same problem but there is a easy solution: Google provides now webfonts for many languages, also ethiopic:
http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess

Answer (score 2):

To write amharic or Tigrigna in web forms you can simply use Any Key firefox add on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/any-key/ and there is for chrome too !!

But To create an editor using javascript you can see a site here http://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/amharic.htm and try to firgure it out how they implemented it !!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at
http://senamirmir.org/

which unless I am wrong has done what you want to do.
If you don't like their fonts SIL Abyssinica should be fine too (but it only includes one writing style).

The layout status will vary from system to system, to target *nix like systems you need a layout merged in
http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/XKeyboardConfig/

Answer (score 1):

@Samaya, by now you probably got the answer you were looking for. But let me drop what I think. Based on your original question, I think you are trying to develop a small software which can be selected as utility(as a feature) and be used to display  Geez alphabets without the need of installing a separate Geez application. For that, I reckon, the utility application should be developed in a way that it could be selected as a feature (language feature) in an operating system (Like Amharic in windows for instance). However, your subsequent comments seem to focus more on displaying Geez characters on a web. As many have suggested, we already have that functionality. But if you still want to develop an application for it, I would suggest you to have unicode (U1260-በ for instance) array and matching transcription array of your choices from a keyboard ( be - በ   for instance). Your application then would use the array of transcription when keyboard key are entered and match them to the unicode to show the right alphabet in Geez. Not sure if I fully understood what you're looking for but I myself with colleagues did a project that included this type of work for the particular application. By the way, do you have to install Geez software to view Tigrigna/Geez transcript based website? If so, check your version of browser.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually the answer I needed then. I was confused when I asked it at first because I barely know enough about the tools and methods to find the vocabulary and after that I shifted my interest towards making other things, but its always been on my mind. I kinda started it though at  https://github.com/eritrea/geez.json/blob/master/geez.json is that what you mentioned with unicode?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. What language are you trying to use to develop it? Keep in mind the  execution time/speed, memory management and efficiency of the language when you are using such an exhaustive array. Good job though.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about Amharic and the implementation is what I need think about as your suggested. I don't have enough time now, but hopefully one day I can make an opensource virtual keyboard for people to integrate into their site.