# Displaying Amharic text correctly in browsers

Tags: javascript, css

I failed to display Amharic language in my website ,i used @font-face in css properties file linked in the main header (dynamic) ,added also font-family to each class where i added amharic language ,but i see only that only text style is rendered but the characters are not changing and displays strange chracters like(በ አማርኛ ለመጻፍ የሚያስችል ኪ ቦርድ)
The problem is when i install the same font under windows ,it shows properly in all browsers.
So how can i substitute and make the website rely on the font i want to display.

Please provide me with good solution. this website is displaying amharic using javascript and something else :

```
<script src="http://www.abugidainfo.com/amharic/wp-includes/js/handleamharic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

http://www.abugidainfo.com/amharic/ =this is the url that display amharic (/amharic/)

what i must use to display amharic in my website too?
Thanks in advance.i hope somebody can come up with a good fix.Thanks again.

CSS/ (just few first lines)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'abyssinica_silregular';
    src: url('abyssinicasil-r.eot');
    src: url('abyssinicasil-r.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('abyssinicasil-r.woff') format('woff'),
         url('abyssinicasil-r.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('abyssinicasil-r.svg#abyssinica_silregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  1.  Document Setup (body, common classes, structure etc)
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    /*font: 100%/1.618 sans-serif;*/
}
a {
    color:#6e757b;
    -webkit-transition: color 100ms ease-in 0ms;
    -moz-transition: color 100ms ease-in 0ms;
    -o-transition: color 100ms ease-in 0ms;
    transition: color 100ms ease-in 0ms;
}
a:hover {
    color:#6b7278; /*008fd5;*/ 
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    color: #444;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 26px;
}
h1, h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
}
#primary h1, #primary h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#primary h2 {
    /*
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: -0.05em;
    color: #777;
*/
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: -0.045em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 2.3em;
}
#primary h1.entry-title {
    line-height: 1.3em;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1.site-title {
    font-size: 1.71429rem;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: -0.045em;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #F96;
}
h1.site-title a {
    color: #080809;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}
h1.site-title a:hover {
    color: #CCCCCC;
}
h1.page-title {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
h1.compact {
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-weight: normal;
    max-width: 70%; 
}
h2.entry-title {
    color: #5d7898;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 24px;
}
p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.714285714;
}
#preroll_placeholder,
#Playerholder,
object,
embed,
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0; /*0 0 20px 0*/
}
```

Comment: The “strange characters” በ አማርኛ ለመጻፍ የሚያስችል ኪ ቦርድ are Amharic (Ethiopian) characters, i.e. what you want to display. If you do not see them properly, then your browser is not using a suitable font. It sounds like you are using some font trickery (using a font with Latin letters replaced by Amharic) instead of properly encoded (Unicode-encoded) text.

Comment: Cf. to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538685/dynamically-generating-geez-unicodes/13539419#13539419 (which is also about using Amharic on the web, despite the somewhat odd title).

Comment: Show some relevant code (HTML and CSS) and specify exactly which font(s) you are using. Providing a URL of a demo page would help, too. With the currently given data, this looks like “unclear what you are asking”.

Comment: what's your css look like?

Comment: Is it possible your header information is working against you? That might explain why the Amharic letters aren't appearing on your site, but did appear when you pasted them in this question. If you haven't done so already, try simplifying your doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and removing any `<meta>` taks that you don't absolutely need.

Comment: No they don't appear correctly in stackoverflow and even in google and on wikipedia.am using <!DOCTYPE html> but have a lot of <meta> tags.

Comment: i need to force display of amharic even to be adapted for all the website!for some area ...

Comment: I'm seeing the Amharic characters in all browsers I've tested: Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer (all on Windows). The fact that you can't see them on your own page, on here, and on Wikipedia suggests to me that the issue is with your computer's configuration rather than with your code.  
  
I'm sure you're wondering if we're all seeing the same thing. Here's a screen shot of the Amharic characters in your question as they're displayed in my browser:  
(http://www.joederose.us/archive/StackOverflow_Amharic.jpg)

Comment: But are you sure you haven't installed any amharic font? like nyala font that come installed on vista //windows 7 that come with support of arabic and a lot of other languages? if i install any amharic language i would see the amharic displayed correctly in any browser !

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the language and UTF are coded accordingly.

```
<html lang="am">
<head>
<title>Title goes here.</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>body goes here <body>
</html>
```