# Checking if string is Encodeable In Gsm0338

Tags: java, unicode

I am working on an SMS application and I send out Unicode characters (Amharic/G'eez). I am using [this example](https://github.com/opentelecoms-org/jsmpp/blob/master/jsmpp-examples/src/main/java/org/jsmpp/examples/SubmitMultipartMultilangualExample.java). The method on line [240](https://github.com/opentelecoms-org/jsmpp/blob/master/jsmpp-examples/src/main/java/org/jsmpp/examples/SubmitMultipartMultilangualExample.java#L240), `isEncodeableInGsm0338()`, is used to check if I should use another encoding or the default encoding.

Here is the code

```
 public static boolean isEncodeableInGsm0338(String isoString) {
    byte[] isoBytes = isoString.getBytes();
    outer:
    for (int i = 0; i < isoBytes.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < isoGsm0338Array.length; j++) {
            if (isoGsm0338Array[j] == isoBytes[i]) {
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < extendedIsoGsm0338Array.length; j++) {
            if (extendedIsoGsm0338Array[j][1] == isoBytes[i]) {
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the catch. The string `"የእንግሊዝ ፕሪምየር ሊግ ነህሴ 6 ይጀምራል።"`, which is clearly Unicode, is returning from that method. My hypothesis being half of each letter.  But I can't support that theory.  If I change the text to `"1. የእንግሊዝ ፕሪምየር ሊግ ነህሴ 6 ይጀምራል።"`, it detects correctly.

What is happening here?

Comment: The example code uses String.getBytes(). And that depends on the "platform default encoding". I can't see which encoding that is supposed to be. You'd better construct a string GSM_0338 of all allowed characters in this charset, and for every character from your SMS text, check whether it's contained in this string. For the check, I don't see a necessity to create bytes from the SMS text.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff That helps. Thanks

Comment: Why not just have `isEncodeableInGsm0338()` call `isoString.getBytes("GSM_0338")` and return true if it succeeds and false if it fails? Or better, use something like [`GsmCharsetProvider`](https://github.com/ixonos/jcimd/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jcimd/charset/GsmCharsetProvider.java) or [Java GSM 03.38 SMS Character Set Translator](https://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/java-gsm-0338-sms-character-set-translator/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau the last link was helpful. But there is no encoding called `GSM_0338` in java's available char-set list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538685/dynamically-generating-geez-unicodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

The method on [line 240](https://github.com/opentelecoms-org/jsmpp/blob/master/jsmpp-examples/src/main/java/org/jsmpp/examples/SubmitMultipartMultilangualExample.java#L240) is as follows.

```
 public static boolean isEncodeableInGsm0338(String isoString) {
        byte[] isoBytes = isoString.getBytes();
        outer:
        for (int i = 0; i < isoBytes.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < isoGsm0338Array.length; j++) {
                if (isoGsm0338Array[j] == isoBytes[i]) {
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < extendedIsoGsm0338Array.length; j++) {
                if (extendedIsoGsm0338Array[j][1] == isoBytes[i]) {
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

As you can see, it uses`isoString.getBytes()` which is encoding dependent. The solution is to compare each `char` by getting the character array using `isoString.toCharArray()`.

Changed

`byte[] isoBytes = isoString.getBytes();`

to

`char[] isoBytes = isoString.toCharArray();`

You might want to name `isoBytes` to something else too. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of mine. It's 20 times faster on 16 char strings than the nested loop, also faster than regexp, `HashSet` and `tableswitch` (by some reason).

```
public class Gsm0338 {

private static final char[] BASIC_CHARS = {
        // Basic Character Set
        '@', '£', '$', '¥', 'è', 'é', 'ù', 'ì', 'ò', 'Ç', '\n', 'Ø', 'ø', '\r', 'Å', 'å',
        'Δ', '_', 'Φ', 'Γ', 'Λ', 'Ω', 'Π', 'Ψ', 'Σ', 'Θ', 'Ξ', 'Æ', 'æ', 'ß', 'É',
        ' ', '!', '"', '#', '¤', '%', '&', '\'', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?',
        '¡', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
        'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Ä', 'Ö', 'Ñ', 'Ü', '§',
        '¿', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
        'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'ä', 'ö', 'ñ', 'ü', 'à',
        // Basic Character Set Extension
        '\f', '^', '{', '}', '\\', '[', '~', ']', '|', '€'
};

private static boolean[] ENCODEABLE_BY_ORD_UP_TO_253 = new boolean[254];
private static Set<Character> ENCODEABLE_REST = new HashSet<>();
static {
    for (int i = 0; i < BASIC_CHARS.length; i++) {
        char ch = BASIC_CHARS[i];
        if (ch <= 253) {
            ENCODEABLE_BY_ORD_UP_TO_253[ch] = true;
        } else {
            ENCODEABLE_REST.add(ch);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isEncodeable(String javaString) {
    final int length = javaString.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        char ch = javaString.charAt(i);
        if (ch <= 253) {
            if (!ENCODEABLE_BY_ORD_UP_TO_253[ch]) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (!ENCODEABLE_REST.contains(ch)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, here is a function that checks if a string is GSM0338 encodable:

```
function IsGSM0338Encodable($sText)   
{    
$pcgsm0338_chars = '@'.'£'.'$'.'¥'.'è'.'é'.'ù'.'ì'.'ò'.'Ç'.'\n'.'Ø'.'ø'.'\r'.'Å'.'å'.'Δ'.'_'.'Φ'.'Γ'.'Λ'.'Ω'.'Π'.'Ψ'.'Σ'.'Θ'.'Ξ'.'Æ'.'æ'.'ß'.'É'.' '.'!'.'"'.'#'.'¤'.'%'.'&'.'\''.'('.')'.'*'.'+'.','.'-'.'.'.'/'.'0'.'1'.'2'.'3'.'4'.'5'.'6'.'7'.'8'.'9'.':'.';'.'<'.'='.'>'.'?'.'¡'.'A'.'B'.'C'.'D'.'E'.'F'.'G'.'H'.'I'.'J'.'K'.'L'.'M'.'N'.'O'.'P'.'Q'.'R'.'S'.'T'.'U'.'V'.'W'.'X'.'Y'.'Z'.'Ä'.'Ö'.'Ñ'.'Ü'.'§'.'¿'.'a'.'b'.'c'.'d'.'e'.'f'.'g'.'h'.'i'.'j'.'k'.'l'.'m'.'n'.'o'.'p'.'q'.'r'.'s'.'t'.'u'.'v'.'w'.'x'.'y'.'z'.'ä'.'ö'.'ñ'.'ü'.'à'.'\f'.'^'.'{'.'}'.'\\'.'['.'~'.']'.'|'.'€';
    
    $sText = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($sText, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $sText);

    for($i = 0, $unChars = strlen($pcgsm0338_chars); $i < strlen($sText); $i++)
        {
        $c = $sText[$i];

        for($j = 0; $j < $unChars && $pcgsm0338_chars[$j] != $c; $j++);
            
        if ($j >= $unChars)
            return false;
        }
        
    return true;
}
```

Comment: With all due respect, how does PHP code help someone who is asking for Java code?